# Android EditText,ButtonEdit not shown properly?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I Have Debugging Android App in Samsung Device.
But Controls is Not Shown Properly Like Below Pictures.

Second Picture Layout Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout">
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button2"
android:id="@+id/btn2"
/>
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button1 is below button2"
android:layout_below="@id/btn2"
android:id="@+id/btn1"
/>
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button3 below button 1"
android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
android:id="@+id/btn3"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose, he/she wanted to ask, why corners are so weird on edittext and buttons views...

Comment: Why corrupt places indicated by the arrow?

Comment: do you use 9-patch images for background or are those default views without design?

Comment: evilone no background image xml code ise above

Comment: emulator is good but I tried both devices but the result is the same